# Convert Response in to String from the API

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, asp.net-web-api

The Rest API I am calling returns the results in the format `"17-adm-070"`when call them in the web browser.

```
     var response_EndPoint = await client_jaxEndPoint.GetAsync(jaxEndPoint_URL);
     var response_fromEndPoint = response_EndPoint.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     string serviceResponse = response_fromEndPoint.ToString();
```

But here the variable `response_fromEndPoint` gets the response in the format `"\"17-adm-070\""`    I need to remove the extra quotes and slashes and just store 17-adm-070 in to the string `serviceResponse`.

Comment: Have you tried using String.Remove() or string.Replace()

Comment: I tried `serviceResponse.Replace("\"", "")` but still seeing the slashes and double Quotes

Comment: That special characters appear only in debug window, actual value is still what is shown on the browser.

Comment: Did you actually assign the Replace() result back to your variable? like `serviceResponse = serviceResponse.Replace("\"", "");`

Comment: something like this  var s = "\"17-adm-070\"";
            s.Replace("\"","").Replace('\',"");